# jquery print out array value and change its CSS

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I have an array

var list= ['A','B','C'], answer=[];

the user will be slecting answers and that will update the answer array.

She/He will be selecting buttons to match up to the list array, and using this

```
 function response(){

 var allcorrect = 1;

        $.each( list, function( index , value ){ 



              if( value === answer[ index ] ) {

                  console.log( 'Yes',  response[ index ]  );


                } else{

                 console.log( 'No', response[ index ] );
                 allcorrect=0;


                } 

        });


                if (allcorrect==1){


              text = "<p> Correct! You answered: " + response[0] + " and " + response[1] + " and " + response[2]+ "</p> <p> The correct response is A, B, C</p>";


                }  
                else {

                if (allcorrect==0){

              text = "<p> Inorrect. You answered: " + response[0] + " and " + response[1] + " and " + response[2]+ "</p> <p> The correct response is supposed to be  A, B, C</p>";

              }
}

}
```

So say the person chooses A, D, C, then it will say incorrect, you answered A D C ... etc

What I want to happen is for A and C, which are two correct responses, to be changed to red font and for D to remain black since it is incorrect.

How do I add a class to this?

Comment: Generally, red is for wrong but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just make each response its own element with an id so you can access it later. While you are creating elements you can just go ahead and add styling to the wrong ones or give them a class as well.

```
$("#test").html("response 1:" + "<p id='response" + 1 + "' class='class'>" + responses[0] + "</p>");
```

or just give each response a unique id that can be accessed later when you check to see if they are correct responses then add the class using .addClass().

```
$("#test").html($("#test").html() + "<br> response 2:" + "<p id='response" + 2 + "'>" + responses[1] + "</p>");

$("#response2").addClass("class");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjbRt/3/

Comment: I didn't even consider this, I was trying for something similar but never arrived at this point. thank you! I can use this to fit what I need